# Angular 8 Image path

Tags: angular

Playing around with Angular 8, can't figure out how to set up the right path to an image in my project.
Tried  and  but no luck. Can someone please advice how to correctly inset an image in component?

The component is in sec/app folder.
The images stored in sec/app/assets/images folder

The path I've tried was:
 but no luck

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXbR5.jpg)

Thanks.

Comment: Show the path you tried. And why do you have two assets folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [provided assets folder](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#application-source-files) for images instead, which is also referenced within the angular.json:

> assets/
>
> Contains image and other asset files to be copied as-is when
>   you build your application.

```
.
├── src
│   ├── app
│   ├── assets <- here
│   └── environments
...
```

Then you can set paths like `assets/image.png`.

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to store your image in your asset folder (which you seem to do)
2. you just reference the image using the src property: `src="assets/images/your_image_name.png"`